# How can I create a URL encoded query string from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I found tons of examples of how to turn an objects keys/values into a URL encoded query string, but I need to use an array of objects and turn them into a query string.

I want to use pure JS or lodash to accomplish this task.

I am supplying an array of objects in this format:

```
[
  { points: "30.09404881287048,-96.064453125" },
  { points: "30.09404881287048,-94.63485717773439" },
  { points: "29.345072482286373,-96.064453125" },
  { points: "29.345072482286373,-94.63485717773439"}
]
```

I need it to be in this format:

```
points=30.09404881287048%2C-96.064453125&points=30.09404881287048%2C-94.63485717773439&points=29.345072482286373%2C-96.064453125&points=29.345072482286373%2C-94.63485717773439
```

I am currently accomplishing this using these two methods:

```
import { map as _map } from 'lodash';

const createQueryStringFromObject = object =>
  _map(object, (value, key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');

const createQueryStringFromArray = array => array.reduce((queryString, object, index) => {
  return queryString + createQueryStringFromObject(object) + (index < array.length - 1 ? '&' : '');
}, '');
```

I find the `reduce` function implementation sloppy though and I think it could be cleaner and more efficient. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I would like to keep the method generic so it can accept an array of objects with any key and not just specifically the key `points`. I also would like to keep the createQueryStringFromObject() method because I need it elsewhere on the site.

Comment: What's the issue? Or are you just asking for opinions?

Comment: Your `reduce` is just another `map` + `join`.

Comment: `yourArray.reduce((appender, val, i) => { appender.append('points', val.points); return appender; }, new URLSearchParams()).toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for a generic implementation that is not specific to any objects containing the key of `points`. Thanks to melpomene's suggestion to just use another map and join, I gave that a shot and I definitely like that format alot more. Much shorter and clear!

```
const createQueryStringFromArray = array =>
  _map(array, object => createQueryStringFromObject(object))
    .join('&');
```

Answer (score 3):

I like your solution, but I think just using built in prototype methods will clean up the code quite a bit:

```
list.map(p => `points=${encodeURIComponent(p.points)}`).join('&')
```

which results in

`"points=30.09404881287048%2C-96.064453125&points=30.09404881287048%2C-94.63485717773439&points=29.345072482286373%2C-96.064453125&points=29.345072482286373%2C-94.63485717773439"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I like the short format. However it seems specific to the object having the key `points` and I would like to keep it more generic.

Comment: Ah I see. I assumed based off the provided sample data that all the items would follow the same shape.